# Overriding an object prototype and disallowing any further overrides

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a library that intercepts all XMLHttpRequest calls and do something before eventually sending out the request, by overriding its prototype, for example:

```
var original_open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;    
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    // my own override logic here before running the original function
    original_open.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

The problem is, I want to **guarantee that when someone uses this library, it is impossible for any other code on the web page to re-override this effect.**

Because otherwise, the website using this library can dynamically load another piece of JS code which simply overrides the `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` again, and the whole purpose of this library is to disallow that.

I thought about freezing the prototype using `Object.freeze()` right after the override, so that no other code can override my own override. The code would look something like this:

```
var original_open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;    
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    // my own override logic here before running the original function
    original_open.apply(this, arguments);
};
Object.freeze(XMLHttpRequest.prototype);
```

My expectation is that, if another piece of code on the same page tries to re-override my own override, it will fail because the prototype has been frozen.

### My question:

1. Is this the correct solution for this problem?
2. Is this truly secure? (No loopholes)?

Comment: You cannot do what you're asking. Freezing a prototype object prevents it from being changed, but it does not prevent another object ending up in front of it on the prototype chain.

Comment: "*Is this truly secure?*" - Definitely not. Client side codes are never "secure". I have no idea why this would be needed.

Comment: *I want to guarantee that when someone uses this library, it is impossible for any other code on the web page to re-override this effect.* There are no guarantees with client side code. That is the nature of it.

Comment: If another library does the same thing, they'll get your version as their `original_open`, so your code will still be called.

Comment: Nothing is truly secure if you have an adversary execute code on your page.

Comment: Also: client code can use `fetch()`...

Comment: Keep in mind that there are many other libraries that intercept XMLHttpRequest. If you did accomplish this, your library could break others that wrap XMLHttpRequest for other reasons (jQuery, sentry.js, rollbar.js, zone.js...)

Answer (score 1):

**Do not freeze the prototype.** This will lead to developer frustration, unexplainable bugs, and no one using your library. You have no way of knowing what other libraries will modify that method, and how they will do it, which leads to you coding for an endless amount of edge cases. Stick to a best practice, and assume that developers are making wise, compatible library selections.

Due to the nature of client side code, you're going to have to assume that other professional libraries will follow best practices. If 5 libraries all modify the prototypical method using the convention you used, all 5 libraries will work together.

For example, these two overrides simply work together:

```js
var old1 = Document.prototype.querySelector;
Document.prototype.querySelector = function(...args) {
  console.log('Override 1');
  return old1.call(this, ...args);
};

var old2 = Document.prototype.querySelector;
Document.prototype.querySelector = function(...args) {
  console.log('Override 2');
  return old2.call(this, ...args);
};

let p = document.querySelector('body');

console.log(p);
```